# Define Visio's AutoConnect connector point preference

Tags: microsoft-visio, microsoft-visio-2010

I've added some inbound/outbound connector points to a rectangle near the corners.

[image: Rectangle]

However, now when I use the AutoConnect to create one of my Quick Shapes it picks these connector points as they are closest to the corners.

[image]

What I would like is to use the "traditional" central connector point.

[image]

Is there a way to define (e.g. via ShapeSheet) a preferred AutoConnect connector point, or otherwise accomplish this change of behaviour for AutoConnect?